# How to upgrade my Python version on Windows 7 without having to re-install all packages?

Tags: python, windows, upgrade

What are the possibilities to upgrade my existing Python installation (in my case from version 3.2.2 to 3.3.0) on my Windows 7 x64 system and not having to re-install all my packages? Is there a convenient/automated solution to do this?
I'd like to end up with only one Python version on my system.

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result? And how did you install additonal packages?

Comment: Yes I did install Python 3.3. After installing it, there are two Python installations on my system. And the new Python does not know my packages.I did not re-install the packages, because I hope there is a more convenient way to "migrate" them to the new python installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is chiefly with packages written in C: they will be linked with the 3.2 Python code.   It might just be a question of re-linking them, but I have had issues with popular packages like `numpy` (I currenty can't get that to compile on 3.3).

The pure Python packages would probably be OK in theory, but honestly, is it worth taking the risk?

It is safer to load the 3.3 versions of the packages, every time.  Stick with 3.2 until you can upgrade everything.  You can have more than one version of Python loaded on Windows, I have 2.6, 2.7, 3.2 and 3.3 co-existing.  You just have to be careful with %PATH%, assoc, and ftype.

Comment: OK, thank you. I did not now that the packages are that version dependent. Your suggestion to stick to 3.2 until all packages are up-to-date than seems to be the wisest thing to do.